# Quadratic variation of an integral of a function of a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm asked to find the quadratic variation of the integral
$\int_{0}^{t} W_s^2 ds$.

Answer (score 4):

The quadratic variation of $$X_t=\int_0^t W_s^2\,ds$$ is 0.
This is because it's an [Ito process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#It%C3%B4_processes) with no $dB_s$ term.

Comment: How do I prove it? Do I have to show the total variation is bounded, and then the quadratic variation is 0.